# Run ESXi on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Can I run ESXi on EC2?

If so, any suggestion how to do that.

I would like to launch an ESXi machine and host routing VNFs in it on AWS.

Comment: AFAIK nested virtualization is not supported but you can get bare metal instances that do support running your own hypervisors, preconfigured with vmware: https://aws.amazon.com/vmware/  or  install your own hypervisor on a `3.metal` : https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/i3/

Comment: @HBruijn Which Amazon Machine Image (AMI) I should choose before selecting i3.large while creating EC2 instance?

Comment: You will probably need to create your own AMI with ESXi as I don't expect Amazon to support and provide any - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html

Comment: @HBruijn that looks very complicated to do. Right now I don't have any ESXi environment from where I can export my AMI image. I thought I would somehow install it from an ESXi image ISO, and that's it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Most organisations are going away from ESXi towards cloud provided virtualization.

Comment: @Tim I just wanted to have ESXi to host certain VMs on AWS in order to have NFV environment in order to set up SRv6 in those VMs (VNFs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VMware Cloud on AWS.](https://aws.amazon.com/vmware/) A pretty big commitment as the minimum cluster size is several hosts and the pricing is "talk to VMware sales".

In theory, you could install ESXi yourself on one of the bare metal instances. Tricky, there is no boot from ISO image, and I don't know what the VM importer would do with an ESXi image.

Comment: Well, speaking of installing an ESXi by myself, I'm looking for a way in which I can export an OVF Template, then import it on AWS.

Comment: What have you attempted to get ESXi onto your own AMI? There is very little information about this, as I don't think either AWS or VMware intended to support do it yourself. I'd expect you to have to install ESXi locally, image that disk, then transplant it into some other AMI.

Comment: I have tried to import an OVA image of ESXi which I deployed in my machine. I followed step by step in the given documentation [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#vmimport-limitations]. I got the following: `"StatusMessage": "ClientError: EFI partition detected. UEFI booting is not supported in EC2.", `

Comment: Talk to your network team and/or VMware and see what networking(?) solutions fit your actual problem. I doubt ESXi is required, also installing it via undocumented procedures is going to be painful and unsupported.

Comment: already did. I got [VMware Cloud on AWS - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/vmware/), and it is 100% meet my needs.